# is it possible to check whether file/folder is modified in sourceGenerators task

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt1.0

I am using sbt `sourceGenerators` task for code generation. i want to skip all files/folders that are unchanged during processing.How can i check if a particular file/folder inside `src/main/scala` is changed or not ...

Comment: I've searched for related functionality and I'm pretty sure that sbt doesn't expose such functionality. You could just instantiate your own file-watcher and use it to monitor files. But that's worth a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

this is usually done using sbt.util.Tracked, there are some examples in sbt itself